# Why do certain TextBoxes not display on my PDF page (iTextSharp)?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I've got several textboxes on a PDF form. Most display fine, with data in them where appropriate, such as the "Required Date" textbox. Others display fine when passed no data (such as "Payment Amount"). Those at the bottom, though, do not display at all. e.g., look at the bottom section of the form, from "Requester / Payee Signature" down through the bottom of that ("Authorization") section - only horizontal lines appear below those labels, rather than the TextBoxes that should be there:

[image]

The code they use is virtually the same:

```
// "Request Date" is an example of those which displays fine:
PdfPCell cellReqDateTextBox = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxReqDate", boxRequestDate.Text)
};
tblFirstRow.AddCell(cellReqDateTextBox);
. . .
doc.Add(tblFirstRow);

// Requester / Payee Signature" stands for all those who foul up:
PdfPCell cellTextBoxRequesterPayeeSignature = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxRequesterPayeeSignature", "Enter signature here")
};
tblSection6_Row2.AddCell(cellTextBoxRequesterPayeeSignature);
. . .
doc.Add(tblSection6_Row2);
```

They both call this:

```
public class DynamicTextbox : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private string fieldname;
    private string fieldvalue;

    public DynamicTextbox(string name, string value)
    {
        fieldname = name;
        fieldvalue = value;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].PdfWriter;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField text = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
        text.Text = fieldvalue;
        PdfFormField field = text.GetTextField();
        writer.AddAnnotation(field);
    }
}
```

The only difference I can see in how they call "DynamicTextbox()" is that the ones that display pass the Text value of a Textbox as the second arg to DynamicTextbox(), whereas the ones that don't work pass a raw string - why would that matter?

Are the "horizontal lines" below the labels the TextBoxes? If so, why are they of such diminutive height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the other text fields belong to a cell in a row that has other content. This other content determines the height of the cell they belong too and as such also the height of the row.

The text fields that look as if they consist of a single line belong to a row with cells that have no content. These cells are added, but their height is zero. When the cell event is executed, the `position` parameter is a rectangle with zero height, hence the result that the fields added in such an event consist of nothing more than a line.

To avoid this, you can either define a minimum height or a fixed height. Minimum height means that the height can get a greater value than the value you define, if you add more content. Fixed height means that content that doesn't fit the height you defined won't be shown.

Use:

```
cellTextBoxRequesterPayeeSignature.FixedHeight = 20f;
```

or:

```
cellTextBoxRequesterPayeeSignature.MinimumHeight = 20f;
```

Adapt the value `20f` to whichever value is most appropriate in the context of your application. The measurement unit is *user units*. The default is that 72 user units equal 1 inch.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again; for my purposes I used:
private const float DYNAMIC_TEXTBOX_MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 16f;